# What's wrong with this Supergirl elevator pitch?

Tags: arrowverse, supergirl

I might be wrong about the term, but I'm talking about the thing that goes like this: "When I was a child, my planet Krypton was dying. I was sent to Earth to protect my cousin". Towards the end, she says "...to protect my city from aliens and anyone that means to cause a harm". Obviously, she is an alien herself and again obviously, there are nice aliens and there are not-so-nice aliens. Why would she say that and generalize all aliens despite she is one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a false premise due to misunderstanding what the character said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The actual quote is

> But in secret, I work with my adoptive sister for the DEO to protect my city from alien life and anyone **else** that means to cause it harm. I am Supergirl.

So she doesn't generalise ALL aliens she's referring to aliens *that mean to cause harm*.

The emphasis is on **mean to cause harm** ...not on who/what is causing the harm.

Arguably, this could come down to punctuation...add a couple of commas and the emphasis becomes clearer.

> But in secret, I work with my adoptive sister for the DEO to protect my city from alien life, and anyone else, that means to cause it harm. I am Supergirl.

Additionally, it's not certain that her city (D.E.O. notwithstanding) has the capacity to deal with aliens *at all*.

Even well-meaning aliens can cause *difficulties* and she is, perhaps, better equipped to deal with them that a normal human.

Comment: It still doesn't explain why she needs to protect the city from alien life. To my knowledge, `alien life` and `everyone else` are separate.

Comment: The way I read it, she mentions her job as part of the DEO.   It's a major theme of the show that she works for this organization that primarily monitors aliens.   She's saying the DEO does that and she works for them.   So, I think Paulie_D has answered the question, but I suppose it's up to how you interpret the sentence.

Comment: It is also not unreasonable to have her consider herself an alien, thus part of her job is to make sure she doesn't do harm to the city either.